# Android and ArrayLIst Size returns 0

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Strange problem I'm having here. I add to an arraylist when the user clicks on the view. I get the position and add it to an ArrayList of coordinates. I then draw a circle on the canvas where the coordinates says to do so. The Size check in onDraw always returns 0.

```
private static ArrayList<Coordinate> coords = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
```

OnTouchEvent

```
...
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
    mLastTouchX = event.getX();
    mLastTouchY = event.getY();
    this.coords.add(new Coordinate(mLastTouchX, mLastTouchY));
    break;
...
```

OnDraw

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    for(int i = 0; i < this.coords.size(); i++) {
        canvas.drawCircle(coords.get(i).x, coords.get(i).y, 30.0f, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the motion event code is ever executed?

Comment: @veer See the comments on my post, his issue appears to be that onDraw is only called once at init, so it never updates with the new coordinates

Answer (score 1):

How are you expecting to get a static field with `this` ? But assuming that's just some typo, try adding some logging:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
    mLastTouchX = event.getX();
    mLastTouchY = event.getY();
    this.coords.add(new Coordinate(mLastTouchX, mLastTouchY));
    System.out.println("Added a coordinate; new size: " + coords.size());//to see if we are adding it
    break;
```

And in your onDraw:

```
System.out.println(coords);//Just to see what all is in it
for(int i = 0; i < this.coords.size(); i++) {
    canvas.drawCircle(coords.get(i).x, coords.get(i).y, 30.0f, mPaint);
}
```

Comment: You can access static methods via an instance.

Comment: Seems like onDraw isn't being called continuously ... when printing coords, I get an empty list. This print occurs one time.

Comment: Ah, yes, was thinking it was flipped. On a different note that, you should probably use the class's name, not this (ex. ClassName.coords, not this.coords)

Comment: @lostdev Are their any other methods that you can override that have to do with painting? I'm not familiar with the android API, but it appears that's the issue (that it's only called once to init)

Comment: My understanding of the Android onDraw() is that its called cyclically. This doesn't seem to be the case. It maybe helpful to know the Class extends View.

Comment: Can 'solve' the issue by calling invalidate() on the view. But I'm not sure this is the correct method as it completely redraws the view.

Comment: Alright, I google it and found an API (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). I don't see a method for repainting manually there, but I could be missing it, so I'll ask anyway; is there a method you could call such as in swing components to repaint it?

Comment: @lostdev I presume that is the repaint method? Well like swing where it forces repaint that is. You cut me off mid-message there and pretty much answered me ;)